# How do I select different std::cmp::Ord (or other trait) implementations for a given type?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use `std::collections::BinaryHeap` with a custom struct. In order to do so, I have to have my struct implement the `std::cmp::Ord` trait, but what I need is 2 `BinaryHeap`s of the same structs but ordered differently.

Is there a way to define 2 Ord implementations & pick which `Ord` gets used, or some other way to specify an alternate ordering?

I think I could define 2 different wrapping structs which keep a reference to the original custom struct and have an implementation of `Ord` for each of them, but it seems quite wasteful to have to construct potentially a lot of instances of such wrapping structs.

In Pyhton/Java I'd provide a sorting function/Comparator, but there seems no facility like that. In Scala, I can define a compile-time only type to select the right implicit Ordering implementation; it feels like Rust supports something similar, but I haven't been able to work it out.

Comment: If you're going to have *two* binary heaps, you would need two binary heaps in any language, and need to fill both with their own (references) to the structs/objects. What's the problem?

Comment: @delnan The problem was not having 2 heaps, but that each heap needs to use different orderings for the same type. Since afaik Rust enforces a 1:1 mapping between types and traits (including between my struct and `Ord`), it wasn't clear to me how I should handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to have two different implementations of the same trait for a single type, e.g. this hypothetical scheme *doesn't* work

```
struct MyType { ... }
mod foo {
    impl Ord for MyType { ... } // A

    // everything in here uses the A implementation
}
mod bar {
    impl Ord for MyType { ... } // B

    // everything in here uses the B implementation
}
```

If you want different behaviours with `BinaryHeap` you do have to just use wrapper types, however, wrapper types are not wasteful, since there is no additional indirection or memory use, `struct Foo { data: T }` and `T` are same, other than the nominal type name (no matter what type `T` is).

Comment: Nice, I was not expecting wrapping types to be free at runtime. Is this is documented anywhere or guaranteed by something? All I could find in the Rust reference was ["the precise memory layout of a structure is not specified"](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#structures).

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, if I wanted to turn say a `Vec<MyStruct>` into a `Vec<WrapperStruct>` to subsequently sort by `WrapperStruct`'s impl of `Ord`, the `map` (or even `map_in_place()`) wouldn't be free, would it? (or is the map optimised away because it can be proved to be a "bit-wise identity function"?)

Comment: Yeah, strictly speaking the layout of structs isn't specified, but there's no sensible change that can be made to a single-field enum: reordering fields does nothing if there's only one field. (I suppose the compiler could, like, insert unnecessary leading padding or something, but that's a little peculiar. Maybe as a tool for fuzzing `unsafe` code?) An iterator-based `map` would not optimise way, `map_in_place` has a chance to, but I haven't checked (and it is a small chance).

Comment: (For the `sort` case specifically, you can use `.sort_by`, e.g. `.sort_by(|a, b| Wrap(a).cmp(Wrap(b))` would work. Of course would could also just define a normal comparator function for doing the sorting.)