# Reverse order Priority Queue

Tags: rust, priority-queue

Does anyone know if it is possible to reverse the order in a priority queue in Rust?
When I peek the queue, I want the lowest i32 to be received. However, it seems that it by default returns the highest i32.

**Edit**

This is the package I am using: docs.rs/priority-queue/1.2.0/priority_queue

Comment: Hi @MaxTorreSchau, you should probably tell which package you are using. As I don't believe this is a native type in rust ? it is this one : https://docs.rs/priority-queue/1.2.0/priority_queue/ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Then maybe take a look at the double priority queue:  https://docs.rs/priority-queue/1.2.0/priority_queue/double_priority_queue/struct.DoublePriorityQueue.html

It seems the `peek_min` will be perfect for your need

Comment: That did indeed solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers man ! Happy to help

Comment: If you don't need to change the order on the fly, another option is to inverse the priorities when pushing an item in the queue. I.e. `push (item, -prio)` instead of `push (item, prio)`.

Comment: Does this anwer your question? [How do I create a BinaryHeap that pops the smallest value, not the largest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489368/how-do-i-create-a-binaryheap-that-pops-the-smallest-value-not-the-largest) It's for a `BinaryHeap`, but the approach works for any data structure that relies on `PartialEq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.rs/priority-queue/1.2.0/priority_queue/) of the crate (package).

I believe you should be using `DoublePriorityQueue` instead of `PriorityQueue` as it offers to `peek` in the queue the highest value or the lowest. Using `peek_max` or `peek_min` respectively.

See the snippet of code they provide in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/priority-queue/1.2.0/priority_queue/double_priority_queue/struct.DoublePriorityQueue.html):

```
use priority_queue::DoublePriorityQueue;

let mut pq = DoublePriorityQueue::new();

assert!(pq.is_empty());
pq.push("Apples", 5);
pq.push("Bananas", 8);
pq.push("Strawberries", 23);

assert_eq!(pq.peek_max(), Some((&"Strawberries", &23)));
assert_eq!(pq.peek_min(), Some((&"Apples", &5)));

pq.change_priority("Bananas", 25);
assert_eq!(pq.peek_max(), Some((&"Bananas", &25)));

for (item, _) in pq.into_sorted_iter() {
    println!("{}", item);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you need to access it from both ends, using [`std::cmp::Reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html) should be the most efficient solution. (e.g. `PriorityQueue<i32, Reverse<i32>>`, `.push(x, Reverse(x))`)

Comment: How do you use it with the PriorityQueue?

Comment: @Jean Does my edit answer your question?

Comment: Perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Actually, how do you access the Reverse<i32> value? Found it, it's a tuple, that's quite confusing. So `reverse_variable.0` gives the value.